# What's wrong with my code? It shows an unwanted result

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll unsigned long long int
using namespace std;

ll solve(ll arr[], ll n, ll b, ll x, ll pos) {
  if(n == b)
    return n;
  ll idx = pos - 1;
  for(ll i = n -1; i >= idx; --i) {
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
  }
  arr[idx] = x;
  return (n + 1);
}

signed main() {
    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
      ll n;
      cin >> n;
      ll arr[n];
      ll b;
      cin >> b;
      for(ll i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
      }
      ll x, pos;
      cin >> x >> pos;
      cout << solve(arr, n, b, x, pos) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Input:

```
1            // testcases
5            // capacity of array
3            // number of elements to be inserting
3 4 7        // array elements
8            // element to be inserting
2            // position of the element
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615
```

Which is wrong. Every time I run this code, it generates a new random big number like this. I want the output to be `[3, 8, 4, 7]`

Please explain what is going on, and how to solve this problem. Basically, whenever I run the program, it generates an unwanted big number. I tried many posible methods, but still the problem is the same.

Comment: `signed main()`?! Who taught you that? Report them to the competent authority ([a starving dog](http://assets.rollingstone.com/assets/2016/article/game-of-thrones-an-appreciation-of-ramsay-bolton-20160622/246022/medium_rect/1466597774/720x405-RS-GOT.jpg)).

Comment: don't use single letter variable names and obfuscating macros if you expect others to read your code. Also read [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) and 
[Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: You have not described you problem or what your code is supposed to do or even the results you're getting. What are all the other methods you mentioned?

Comment: @Enlico then suggest me how write a code but this time i need help i am new in cpp

Comment: @roczyou, and you are new to SO, so go read [repro]. And then start with a book or online resource. You don't learn a language by starting to throw random stuff at it.

Comment: Don't use `ll arr[n];`. It's a VLA and it's not standard C++. It's an extension only available in some compilers.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes i remember that next time

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: You access the array out of bounds in `arr[i + 1] = arr[i];`  since `i + 1 == 5`. You can only access `arr[0]` to `arr[4]` so your program has undefined behavior

Comment: @TedLyngmo its a basic insert operation but i wanted to return a whole array at the end with inserted element

Comment: Does your input file really contain those `//` strings?  They will result in input failures, but you never tested for those (e.g. with `if (!std::cin)` or by `std::cin.execptions(std::ios_base::fail|std::ios_base::bad)`).  If you had bothered to make your program _minimal_, you would have discovered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to debug your code. If you can't do that with a debugger, write a function which prints to the screen the relevant information, such as the following:

```cpp
void paxDebug(const char *desc, ll arr[], ll sz, ll n, ll b, ll x, ll pos) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    cout << "n = " << n << " b = " << b << " x = " << x << " pos = " << pos << "\n";
    for (ll i = 0; i < sz, ++i)
        cout << " arg[" << i << "] = " << arg[i];
    cout << "\n==========\n";
}
```

This will produce something like:

```
<Description>
n = 9 b = 9 x = 9 p = 9
arr[0] = 9 arr[1] = 9 arr[2] = 9 arr[3] = 9 arr[4] = 9
=========
```

Then pepper your code with calls to this function at many different places, such as:

```cpp
ll solve(ll arr[], ll n, ll b, ll x, ll pos) {
  paxDebug("start solve", arr[], n, n, b, x, pos);

  if(n == b)
    return n;

  ll idx = pos - 1;
  for(ll i = n -1; i >= idx; --i) {
    paxDebug("in solve loop", arr[], n, n, b, x, pos);
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
  }

  paxDebug("after solve loop", arr[], n, n, b, x, pos);

  arr[idx] = x;

  paxDebug("just before solve return", arr[], n, n, b, x, pos);

  return (n + 1);
}
```

This should allow you to analyse the values of those variables, an invaluable aid to diagnosing what your issue is.

---

And please, for the sake of those who must maintain your code in future (even if it's *you* six months from now), use better variable names :-)